# Mathematical distinction between unit sphere, unit ball, unit box and unit cube as a constraint?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I've been given a few questions where we've been given some of the above listed as constraints. I thought I had a clear idea on how to do the problems but I get unreasonable equations. This has led me to believe I don't actually understand how to set up constraints and I'd appreciate it if someone could explain how. I'm most concerned with setting up a unit sphere, ball and cube.

**My current understanding:**

**unit box**: we look only at the edges/surfaces of the box to find max and min
**unit cube**: the "boundary" is every point inside the cube plus the outer edges/surfaces
**unit sphere**: outer surface of the sphere is where we're checking for max and min
**unit ball**: the inside + surface of the ball is where we're looking for max and mins

**My current mathematical representation of constraints:**

**unit sphere**: $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$
**unit ball**:$\frac{4}{3}\pi x^3$ (?)

**unit cube**: ${0 ≤ x ≤ 1, 0 ≤ y ≤ 1, 0 ≤ z ≤ 1}$, $xyz=1$  (?)
**unit box**: I think I'd need multiple equations to test the boundary?

Comment: The boundary doesn't contain any interior points

Comment: The unit ball is defined to be the set of points whose distance to the origin is less or equal to $1$, so it is defined by the inequality $x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1$. In the unit cube, I don't know why you require $xyz=1$, for instance, the point $(0,0,0)$ is in the cube but the product of its componets is $0$.

Comment: @Javi Thank you! If I were attempting to constrain some function within a ball, would I have to use the equation with the inequality or is there some other way I can about finding the max and minima?

Comment: Usually, you search for local extrema in the interior of the ball and then on the boundary, which is the unit sphere. I guess the procedure dependes on the particular problem, but the region is that, you can change the way it is expressed changing coordinates or whatever, but that's it.

Answer (score 1):

For the box, it is the cube constraints and at least one of $x,y,z$ at one of its bounds.  You can write that part as $x(1-x)y(1-y)z(1-z)=0$.